# Вывести Категории и подкатегории (Drupal)?

Tags: drupal

Каким образом через Views можно вывести список в таком виде?

[image]

На данный момент получается только вывести все категории с помощью группировки по родителю.
Но мне нужен только первый уровень вложения. Связи с глубиной таксономии нету в фильтрах.

Answer (score 1):

**Решил следующим образом:**

> #### Формат
>
> *Формат: HTML список => Групп. поле N.1: (Родитель) Термин таксономии: Название*
>
> *Показать: Поля*
>
> #### Поля
>
> *Термин таксономии: Название*
>
> *(Родитель) Термин таксономии: Название*
>
> #### Критерии фильтрации
>
> *Словарь таксономии: Машинное имя (= Каталог)*
>
> *(Родитель) Термин таксономии: Родительский термин (= )*
>
> #### Связи
>
> *Термин таксономии: Родительский термин*